# Check last saved date on all CSV files in a folder

Tags: vba, csv, excel, last-modified

Pretty simple question really, I suppose. How can I amend the below so that rather than looking at LOI.CSV it looks at all .CSV files in the Intraday Folder?

```
LastSaved = FileDateTime("W:\Settlements\Intraday\LOT.csv")

If LastSaved < Date Then
  MsgBox ("The current day file for LOI was last saved " & LastSaved)
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Const sPath As String = "W:\Settlements\Intraday\"

Sub LoopThroughFilesInAFolder()
    Dim StrFile As String

    StrFile = Dir(sPath & "\*.Csv")

    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        Debug.Print FileDateTime(sPath & "\" & StrFile)
        '~~> Rest of the code here
        StrFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thats the ticket... thanks very much, i was working something similar but missed the * out.